# group data based on Time

Tags: c#

I have one config list like below,

```
public class Config
{
    public string CMasterName { get; set; }
    public string cChildName { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}

 List<Config> config = new List<Config>(){
        new Config { CMasterName ="MasterName1", cChildName="ChildName1", Hours=5}
        };
```

**"5" hrs group for "MasterName1" & "ChildName1"**

Now I have PointData list with below data,

```
public class PointData
{
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public string DataDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDateTime { get; set; }
    public string MasterName { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

 List<PointData> pointData = new List<PointData>(){
        new PointData { DataId = 1, DataDescription="Desc 1", InsertDateTime = new DateTime(2016, 9, 8, 7, 10, 24), MasterName ="MasterName1", ChildName="ChildName1"},
        new PointData { DataId = 2, DataDescription="Desc 2", InsertDateTime = new DateTime(2016, 9, 8, 8, 10, 24), MasterName ="MasterName1", ChildName="ChildName1"},
        new PointData { DataId = 3, DataDescription="Desc 3", InsertDateTime = new DateTime(2016, 9, 8, 10, 10, 24), MasterName ="MasterName1", ChildName="ChildName1"},
        new PointData { DataId = 4, DataDescription="Desc 1", InsertDateTime = new DateTime(2016, 9, 8, 14, 10, 24), MasterName ="MasterName1", ChildName="ChildName1"}
        };
```

**Here, first 3 datapoints are within 5 hrs time range for "MasterName1" & "ChildName1" and last datapoints are beyond 5 hrs time**

Now I would to match "datapoints" list with "config" list in a such way that first 3 records of "datapoints" will convert to 1 record and 4th record of "datapoints" will be a separate record.

Please suggest!!!

The result should be a list with one more column "count", like below,
[image]

Comment: How can you say that three PointData are within a 5 hours range from MasterName1 if MasterName1 has no DateTime?

Comment: How can `dataId 3`, `DataDescription DESC 3` have a count of 3 ? There is only one record for 3.  And all five records get a different InsertDateTime. Hiow is it that the two rows in your desired reults have the same insertDateTime?

Comment: as "dataId 3" has max datetime within 5h range, hence i want this as output for first 3 records with count 3

Comment: I just edited the sample data and output

Comment: I'm completely clueless as to why you're doing what you're doing or really even what you're doing. But I answered with a loop to create a sublist of every three datapoints. If you'd like to explain what you're trying to accomplish maybe I can help more.

Comment: How can you merge items with different descriptions? At least, you should write _multiple_ instead of the value of the last item.

Comment: Sort data and then merge items as desired. You won't get such weird behavior without writing your own code.

Comment: List "PointData" has 4 records with InsertDate as "(2016, 9, 8, 7, 10, 24)", "(2016, 9, 8, 8, 10, 24)", "(2016, 9, 8, 10, 10, 24)" and "(2016, 9, 8, 14, 10, 24)". Take first record "InsertDate " as base date/time, from 2nd records onward I need to look for every records and within 5 hrs of "InsertDate" I need to skip the records. if it is beyond 5h, then again a new record in new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime lowDate = pointData.First().InsertDate;
foreach(PointData pD in pointdata)
        {
            DateTime test = pD.InsertDate;
            List<PointData> subList = pointData.Where(p => p.InsertDate > lowDate && <= test.AddHours(5));
        }
```

Comment: I want to compare 2 list

Comment: Yes - convert thisSubList into a single record however you want to merge the three inputs, then compare it to whatever you'd like.

Comment: as first 3 data are within 5 hrs (against my config list), hence I want to merge with 1 record, Is this possible?

Comment: my both lists are not fixed, multiple config data for "CMasterName" and "cChildName" and against those config we have 10-100 data points records

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish - "I have list of ... called CMasterName and list of ... called cChildName. MasterName and ChildName get filled by.... I need to ...."

Comment: List "PointData" has 4 records with InsertDate as "(2016, 9, 8, 7, 10, 24)", "(2016, 9, 8, 8, 10, 24)", "(2016, 9, 8, 10, 10, 24)" and "(2016, 9, 8, 14, 10, 24)". Take first record "InsertDate " as base date/time, from 2nd records onward I need to look for every records and within 5 hrs of  "InsertDate" I need to skip the records. if it is beyond 5h, then again a new record in new list